# Viewport giving different screen sizes for each orientation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, viewport

I am building an phonegap app using html5 and css. I have a iBall slide android tablet with screen resolution 800*480.

But when i open the page and check its width using java script it shows different values for all orientation. 
I am using this as meta value for viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```

Plus the most confusing part is that when the app is started for the first time after installation, it shows different screen width and height for same orientation when the app is started second or third time.

There are my values:
1st time in landscape mode:
**width**:640
**height**:359

1st time in portrait mode:
**width**:384
**height**:615

after 1st time in landscape mode:
**width**:800
**height**:449

after 1st time in portrait mode:
**width**:800
**height**:1281

How am i supposed to target all these screen sizes?

Comment: Can you show me the code that you use to retrieve the window size?

Comment: i used simple alert(screen.width); alert(screen.height); function to check sizes

Comment: Do you used http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/height/ ?

Try to put the alert after a 

$(window).load(function() {
   alert($(window).height());
   alert($(window).width());
});

Comment: @albertopriore its now giving same these value each time 
for portrait:
800 * 1281

for landscape:
640 * 359

Comment: So why it was showing different values each time? And how can i target these sizes, there are no similarities in landscape and portrait mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you used api.jquery.com/width and api.jquery.com/height ?

Try to put the alert like this

```
$(window).load(function() { 
   alert($(window).height()); 
   alert($(window).width()); 
});
```

then try to put this

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
   alert($(window).height()); 
   alert($(window).width()); 
});
```

and then tell me what's happens if you rotate your device.

Comment: no i didn't used jquery width and i tried ur resize code and its giving 800 * 1281 for portrait and 449*800 for landscape.

Comment: yeah actually i hardcoded the width manually so now its working...but still need to work on different sizes of view port. Thanks anyway :)